# Do Ribbons have other effects besides for Contests?

Tags: pokemon-series

Starting in gen III, we can get Ribbons for our individual Pokemon.

If I remember correctly, in gen III we need Ribbon for contest purpose, for example, to have access Master Rank, we need Ribbons from Normal, Super, and Hyper Rank.
Up until now, few Ribbons can we obtained like Effort Ribbon.

So, do these Ribbons have another effect/purpose outside of contests? Do we really need to collect all Ribbons for our Pokemon?

Comment: No you don't, they're only aesthetic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ribbons don't change in any way the Pokémon they're awarded to.

As you mentioned, they're used to grant access to Contests, and you need 10 different ribbons on party Pokémon in order to gain access to the Ribbon Syndicate in Pokémon Diamond, Pearl, and Platinum.

Answer (score 2):

The Ribbons don't affect statistics of your pokémon. It's more a collectable things.

Comment: I know you're the first to answer my question, but, I like @DanmakuGrazer 's answer because it's give me at least  new information about Ribbon Syndicate (I don't even know this Ribbon exist)

Comment: No problem. I understand.